# Release and pushViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a custom view controller that I push onto my navigation stack as follows:

```
myViewController *myVC = [[myViewController alloc] init];
[myVC generate:myData];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myVC animated:YES];
```

the code runs fine, but when checking for memory leaks I get a warning that myVC is never released.

adding a release statement

```
[myVC release];
```

in line 4 compiles fine, but crashes in execution. How do I need to handle this?

Comment: If you have the release statement after pushViewController call it should work. What is the error message?

Comment: The crash comes when popping the previous view - error [CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4950800
(gdb)

Comment: where and how are you popping the view ?

Comment: when I click the back-button on the top viewcontroller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that it has nothing to do with this section of code.  The problem is that before, since you weren't releasing it here, it was never deallocated.  Now that it is being deallocated when you pop the view controller from the navigation stack, it's calling the `dealloc` method of `myViewController`, and some string object is being over-released in there.

Presumably at some point some string variable is set inside your `myViewController` without retaining it or it is released without being set to null, then later you release it again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should release your view controller.

The error message you see results from a memory management problem inside your view controller - it would seem that you over-release a `NSString` object.

Answer (score -3):

You should use

```
myViewController *myVC = [[myViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]
```

When creating new view controllers, it seems that using init instead of initWithNibName with nil arguments messes things up for pushViewController. This was a problem that took me hours to solve since it *seems* unrelated to the issue at hand!

Comment: This won't even compile as written and is unrelated to the issue at hand.